# Bounds for the extreme singular-values of random matrix with thresholded entries

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, random-matrices, measure-concentration, free-probability

Let $n,d,k$ be large positive integers such that $\max(n/d,k/d) =: \lambda < 1$. Let $X$ be a random $n \times d$ matrix with entries drawn iid from $N(0,1/d)$ and let $W$ be a $k \times d$ random matrix, independent of $X$,  with entries drawn iid from $N(0,1/d)$. Consider the $n \times k$ matrix $C$ defined by $c_{ij} = \max(x_i^\top w_j, 0)$.

> **Question.** What are good bounds for the extreme singular-values of $C$ ?

### Empirical observations

[image]
**Related:** https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4031609/168758

Comment: @oferzeitouni I've added a figure from simulations. There seems to be concentration of the extreme singular-values $C$ but I have no clue how to prove it.

Comment: You are basically asking about the top eigenvalue of a product of two Wishart matrices. Corollary 2.2 in Male's paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1004.4155.pdf should be enough to show that the spectrum is contained in the limiting spectrum (which can be computed using free probability).

Comment: @oferzeitouni Thanks for the input. What about the case where the entries of the product are thresholded (as in my question) ? (from a quick look, the paper you linked doesn't seem to cover this) ? My real issue is the thresholding, not the product (which as you say, is covered by classical results). That is, I'm interested in the singular-values of $C=\psi(XW^\top)$, where $\psi(t):=\max(t,0)$  is applied entrywise.

Comment: I missed that. Not sure. Have you tried to compute high moments?

Comment: You mean like moments of $c_{ij}$ ? A quick calculation gives $\mathbb E [c_{ij}] = \mathcal O(1/\sqrt{d})$ and $\mathbb E[c_{i,j}^2]=\mathcal O(1/d)$. In fact, it should also be possible to compute $\mathbb E[(c_{ij}c_{i'j'})^p]$ say for $p=1,2$; this presumably decays rapidly as a function of $d$. Given such correlation information, are there any general tools that can give info abound extreme singular-values of $C$ (I'm guessing this is what you have in mind, but I may be wrong).

Comment: I meant n^{-1} E Tr (C C^*)^k for large k (k of order log n or so).

Comment: @oferzeitouni One has $\mathbb E\mbox{Tr}(CC^\top) = \sum_i \sum_k \mathbb E[(x_i^\top w_j)_+^2]  = nk/(2\pi d) \lesssim nk/d$. Likewise, $E[(\mbox{Tr}(CC^\top)^2] = \sum_i \sum_k \sum_{i'}\sum_{j'}\mathbb E[(x_i^\top w_j)_+^2(x_{i'}^\top w_{j'})_+^2] \lesssim (nk/d)^2$. More generally, it would seem $\mathbb E \mbox{Tr}(CC^\top)^p \lesssim_p (nk/d)^p$ for every positive integer $p$. Is this to be plugged into some kind of matrix Chebychev inequality, or  did you had something else in mind ? References / pointers welcome.

Comment: Typo: $\sum_{k}$ should be $\sum_{j=1}^k$; etc.

Comment: The classical way to get (upper) estimates on the top eigenvalue is precisely using such computations (see e.g. the section on that in Anderson-Guionnet-Zeitouni). The constant in the $\simeq_p$ is important! (ie, its rate of growth in $p$). But maybe you meant, the smallest singular value?

Comment: Thanks, thanks makes sense. It would be great and very helpful if you could reference a specific section of your book (as it's quit vast) which would be relevant to this this "classical way to get estimates of the top eigenvalues ... $\lesssim_p$ is important ..". Also, indeed my ultimate interest is in the smallest singular-value, but the largest singular-value is also of significant interest to me.

Comment: @oferzeitouni After some rapid digging, it seems (but I may be mistaken) you're talking about the computations of the kind done page page 25 and the end of page 24 of (book link) http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~zeitouni/cupbook.pdf: a combination of spectral norm / trace inequality, and then Markov inequality.

Comment: Yes, I meant that. The main issue is the combinatorics.

Comment: Yes, the combinatorics seem to be very tricky. In fact, the $n^k$ factor in my previous bound seems to be very suboptimal. Trying to reducing it via more careful counting.

Comment: It turns out that $\lambda_\max(CC^\top)$ can be obtained rather easily. Indeed, one observes that $(x_i^\top w_j)_+^2 \le (x_i^\top w_j)^2\;\forall i,j$, and so $\mathbb E[\mbox{Tr}(CC^\top)^p]^{1/p} \le (\mathbb E [\mbox{Tr}(XW^\top WX^\top)^p])^{1/p} \to \alpha$ in the limit $p \to \infty$, for some definite $\alpha \in (0, \infty)$ (thanks to, ae.g using Corollary 2.2 of Male's paper you linked). Thus, we deduce that $\lambda_{\max}(CC^\top) = \mathcal O_{\mathbb P}(1)$ (the result can presumably be made more precise, i.e more precise confidence interval).

Comment: This can be generalized to the case $c_{ij} = \psi(x_i^\top w_j)$ where $\psi:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ with $|\psi(a)| \le |a|$ for all $a \in \mathbb R$ (e.g, any $1$-Lipschitz $\psi$ with $\psi(0)=0$ will do).

Answer (score 1):

> **Claim.** *Rescale things so that $\mathbb E [c_{11}^2] = 1$. In the limit when $n,k \to \infty$ such that $k/n=\lambda \in(0,\infty)$, the spectral density of $C$ converges to $MP(\lambda)$.*

*Proof.* Follows from directly **Corollary 6** of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.08560.pdf). In fact the same result holds if we consider the general scenario in which $c_{ij}:=\psi(x_i^\top w_j)$, with $\psi:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that $|\psi(t)| \le \alpha(1 + |t|)^\alpha$ for some $\alpha \ge 0$ and for every $t \in \mathbb R$. $\quad\Box$